# Python Random Function for Payload function is not working

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, durandal, bots, random

I have one problem with random functions of python.I don't know which random function will work for this code:

```
name=['toffla','rebecca','toff','becca']

if (parser.getPayload().lower() == name):
                        parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(),"what?")
```

If someone input any name from these 4 names, the output should be "what?".

how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use 'if' with "in" operator. Because "name" is not a string. 
if input == name: <- always false. Because input == 'toffla' its not list.
example:

```
>>> name = "bugra"
>>> names = ["github","bugra","turkey","developers"]
>>> name == names
False
>>> name in names
True
```

i hope you know!

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much my brother. it worked.
I am noob, I know even know basics of python.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Bharat no problem, if its work please tick it. For other developers can see it. Click the tick :D